# Map Network Drive only on home network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, mapped-drive

my question is about Mapping a drive.
I have a server at home with a couple of drives attached for storage.  But i use my laptop at work and when ever i map the drives at home, when i get to work i always get the message (unable to connect mapped drives).

Is there a way to get windows to recognize my home network and map the drives when i login.  my question is about.

Does Windows allow me to map based on Network.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think mapped drives can do what you're after.  Instead, would you consider simply using shortcuts to UNC paths? You can pin them as "Favorites" to the sidebar in Explorer, right-click drag-and-drop shortcuts to the desktop, etc.

Comment: You can definitely do this in multiple ways. For you it sounds like creating a batch or powershell script would do the trick. In the script, identify the connected network and either map the drive or don’t. Don’t mark the mapping as persistent so that it disconnects the next time you log off.

Answer (score 0):

Michael J. Burns' Network Drive Control might be the utility you need. From the author's page:

"Network Drive Control allows you to configure the automatic mapping of network drives when you logon based on the network(s) to which you are connected. An example would be to have your laptop automatically connect and map one set of network drives when at home, and another set of network drives when at work or school, and none if it detects that the PC is connected to a network where no mappings have been configured."

http://www.michaelburns.net/Software/NDC/

Sorry for the terrible formatting. Doing this from my phone.